# RuntimeError: Please make sure R is installed (edited)

Tags: python, github, anaconda, spyder, command-prompt

I am trying to use the loadshape package from github (https://github.com/LBNL-ETA/loadshape)

When I type in

```
pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/eetd-loadshape.git@master
```

the following error occurs

```
Collecting git+https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/eetd-loadshape.git@master
  Cloning https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/eetd-loadshape.git (to revision master) to c:\users\fulld\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1
  Running command git clone -q https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/eetd-loadshape.git 'C:\Users\fulld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\fulld\anaconda3\envs\MRCH\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\fulld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\fulld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\fulld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\fulld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\fulld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4_g9awz1\setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        if len(RHOME) == 0: raise RuntimeError("Please make sure R is installed.")
    RuntimeError: Please make sure R is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried the following solutions provided by others:

1. `pip install auto-py-to-exe`
2. deleted anaconda and reinstalled it with variable path checked
3. changed my PC setting language to English
4. `pip install pygetwindow==0.0.1`
5. `pip install -U setuptools`
6. `conda install -c r r-base`
7. `conda install git`

But none of them seems to work and trial no.6 and no.7 also printed out the error(PackagesNotFoundError).

I would really appreciate any help to solve the problem that I'm facing, 'cause I'm totally lost.

------ edited ------

I already have R installed in my computer,
[at C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hel8v.png)

but the error appeared. Do I have to relocate the program files to certain place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

This suggest you should install [R language software](https://www.r-project.org/), so when you type `R` in terminal interactive R console appear.

Comment: I already have R language software in my computer, do I have to change the location of the R folder to specific location?

Comment: @DaJI you should add directory where `R` executable resides to your `PATH`, see for example https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/ After successfully changing `PATH` you should be able to summon `R` in terminal by typing `R`

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and helpful reply. In my case, R was installed in C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.4\bin\x64 . And it also asked me to install R package "ooptparse", which I installed through anaconda prompt with (R -> install.packagges("optparse")) Hope it helps future lost people like me. Thanks again and have a nice day @Daweo !

Answer (score 0):

That means, firstly, you want to install the [R language](https://www.r-project.org/). Then, error fixes.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed R with the dedicated installer, then you just need to set the PATH environment variable to include the directory of R.exe. If you haven't already installed R and you are using Anaconda on Windows, you can indeed [install R with conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/). Maybe insert a step to restart the Anaconda prompt after doing so.

1. Install Anaconda or Miniconda, optionally create new Python 3 environment per user guide instructions, e.g. `conda create -n r_env`
2. Open Anaconda prompt (if using environment, also `conda activate r_env`)
3. Make sure you have basic packages: `conda install git pip setuptools`
4. Install R via conda: `conda install -c r r-essentials r-base r-optparse`
5. Try running R: `R`. If it doesn't start an interactive R session, close the Anaconda prompt and open it again. Check `path`. I have something like `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\r-env\Scripts` in the path, where there is `R.exe`.
6. Finally install the package, `pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/eetd-loadshape.git@master`
7. Test it out: `python -c "import loadshape"`. If there is an error at this point, uninstall the package with `pip uninstall loadshape`, then use git to clone the repository and debug. Maybe would help to know which version of Python the package uses.